# Highlight additional symbols in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, themes, syntax-highlighting

I'm pretty happy with the syntax highlighting, or coloring, in Eclipse.

One thing that bugs me though is that the symbols `|| && == <= >=` are not a different color from surrounding text.

Is there a way to, like one would in an editor like Notepad++, assign these symbols an additional color?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's Eclipse's help docs on syntax coloring, perhaps this can help: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Feditor%2Fref-preferences-syntax-coloring.htm

Comment: @oxguy3 That only appears to allow you to just previously built-in colors for things it already colors by default. Not add additional symbols for highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a single presentation for all operators, including the ones you mention.

In Eclipse preferences under **Java>Editor>Syntax Coloring**, select the element **Java>Operators**. Then click the color chooser.

Refer picture

[image]